# Working with Year , week and Leap year in SQL Server

Tags: date, t-sql, sql-server-2017, leap-year

I'm trying to work with Year and Week in combination and would like to include leap years when they occur.

In my code I'm only adding year + week and I'm not getting what I desire. I would like to have '202101' if I change my code to '+3' because this year there are 53 weeks and the 54 week should 01.

```
(SELECT 
     LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120), 4)  + 
         CAST((DATEPART(ISOWK, GETDATE()) + 3) AS NVARCHAR(2)))
```

I would like to be able to change my code like this

- ...`GETDATE()) + 2)` in my code should return **202053**
- ...`GETDATE()) + 3)` in my code should return **202001**
- ...`GETDATE()) + 4)` in my code should return **202002**

etc...

[image]

Might it be that i should change my code and not have it as a 2 part YYYY and WW but rather combine it as a date? I would believe its a string now.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. It is unclear what the purpose of your code is.

Comment: Have update, hopefully more helpful?

Comment: Do you want +3 and +4 to be in 2020, or 2021?

Comment: I want to have a code that has YYYYWW in it (ISOWK) but in the code i want to be able to add weeks in combination with year